# SQL Server 2005 Compact and SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition be installed in the same server environment as SQL Server 2005?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed they can. SQL Server CE is an embeddable database that runs inside your application process. It does not interact with other processes. You can even have multiple SQL CE applications running on the same machine.